# The shifted library

Tags: cipher, pattern, knowledge

I'm keeping an alphabetically sorted (somehow) collection of books in my library. Unfortunately somebody shifted things around a bit and then deleted some stuff in all of the resulting pairs. Only the 26th pair is a correct match, I believe, although that's been scrambled even more and has become completely unrecognizable now. Can you figure what it used to be? The numbers might help you.

Here are the 25 shifted pairs:

> **{3,8}** $\implies$ CHL DC - FT
>   **{6,1}** $\implies$ MLYB - GAXPCAS
>   **{9,9}** $\implies$ JAMJOYC - WUTHRINGHIGHT
>   **{4,3}** $\implies$ FODOR DOTOVK - UL
>   **{9,2}** $\implies$ JLG - CMPUHMT
>   **{9,5}** $\implies$ DLDFO - THCTCHRTHRY
>   **{1,9}** $\implies$ ????? - BINSNCUS
>   **{1,11}** $\implies$ MAMLVLL - TGTY-FOU
>   **{9,11}** $\implies$ GERGE ELT - MBY-DCK
>   **{1,6}** $\implies$ JONTN SWFT - MDDLEMRC
>   **{4,1}** $\implies$ MKWN - GULLVE'SVELS
>   **{1,4}** $\implies$ W - THDVNTUFHUKBYFNN
>   **{4,5}** $\implies$ BMSTK - LICINWNDLND
>   **{14,17}** $\implies$ MIGE E EVNTES -
>   **{5,8}** $\implies$ JRRLK - DQUX
>   **{8,2}** $\implies$ AYPW -  RDFRIGS
>   **{17,1}** $\implies$ GBRLGRRQZ -  DNTOTHSOFT
>   **{3,7}** $\implies$ P - ONUNDDYSOFSOITUD
>   **{7,2}** $\implies$ JEUSE - OKILLMOCKIGBIRD
>   **{4,7}** $\implies$ LOTOLSTOY - PRIDANDPRJUDIC
>   **{5,3}** $\implies$ THUCODOYL - KI
>   **{1,9}** $\implies$ M - THEHUFTHESEES
>   **{13,14}** $\implies$ ERNES HEMNGWY - LOL
>   **{4,12}** $\implies$ XRU - THOTH
>   **{4,7}** $\implies$ AYLLY - TTUKT

And the 26th is:
**{10,N/A}** $\implies$ TTKJTKZU - DFJ

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Continuing from @Roger's answer, which shows how to get meaning out of the groups of letters,

> the numbers refer to letter positions in the author names. 
> The first numbers end up spelling the alphabet (3rd in Charles Dickens is A, 6th in Emily Bronte is B, ...)
>  The second numbers, still taken from the author, spell out
> DECODEWITHMISSINGLASTNAME
> The "missing last name" refers to the 7th entry, which is George Orwell; it was missing (or just question marks) in the original list. 
> Using a Vigenere cipher with ORWELL as the key, we can decode the 26th entry as:
> FCOFIZLD - HBY
> which can be filled in to give: 
> **F SCOTT FITZGERALD - THE GREAT GATSBY**

Comment: Nice work!! +1 for you

Comment: Well done! That's the right answer!

Answer (score 8):

Partial answer:

> The authors and their books are shifted one row apart.

Don't understand the significance of the numbers yet, but the authors and books I've managed to decipher so far:

{3,8} ⟹⟹ CHL DC - FT

> CHarLes DiCkens - FrankensTein

{6,1} ⟹⟹ MLYB - GAXPCAS

> eMiLY Bronte - GreAt eXPeCtAtionS (credit to @Deusovi)

{9,9} ⟹⟹ JAMJOYC - WUTHRINGHIGHT

> JAMes JOYCe - WUTHeRING HeIGHTs

{4,3} ⟹⟹ FODOR DOTOVK - UL

> FyODOR DOsToyeVsKy - ULysses

{9,2} ⟹⟹ JLG - CMPUHMT

> J.d. saLinGer (credit to @n_palum) - CriMe and PUnisHMenT

{9,5} ⟹⟹ DLDFO - THCTCHRTHRY

> DanieL DeFOe - THe CaTCHeR in THe RYe (credit to @n_palum)

{1,9} ⟹⟹ ????? - BINSNCUS

> george orwell - roBINSoN CrUSoe

{1,11} ⟹⟹ MAMLVLL - TGTY-FOU

> herMAn MeLViLLe - nineTeen eiGhTY-FOUr

{9,11} ⟹⟹ GERGE ELT - MBY-DCK

> GEoRGE ELioT - MoBY-DiCK

{1,6} ⟹⟹ JONTN SWFT - MDDLEMRC

> JOhNaThaN SWiFT - MiDDLEMaRCh

{4,1} ⟹⟹ MKWN - GULLVE'SVELS

> MarK tWaiN - GULLiVEr'S traVELS

{1,4} ⟹⟹ W - THDVNTUFHUKBYFNN

> leWis carroll - THe aDVeNTUres oF HUcKleBerrY FiNN

{4,5} ⟹⟹ BMSTK - LICINWNDLND

> BraM SToKer (credit to @n_palum)  - aLICe IN WoNDerLaND

{14,17} ⟹⟹ MIGE E EVNTES -

> MIGuEl dE cErVaNTES - dracula (credit to @n_palum)

{5,8} ⟹⟹ JRRLK - DQUX

> JRR toLKein - Don QUiXote

{8,2} ⟹⟹ AYPW - RDFRIGS

> AnthonY PoWell (credit to @kayzeroshort) - the loRD oF the RInGS (credit to @Deusovi)

{17,1} ⟹⟹ GBRLGRRQZ - DNTOTHSOFT

> GaBRieL GaRcia maRQueZ - a DaNce TO THE muSic OF Time (credit to @kayzeroshort)

{3,7} ⟹⟹ P - ONUNDDYSOFSOITUD

> harPer lee - ONe hUNDred DaYS OF SOlITUDe

{7,2} ⟹⟹ JEUSE - OKILLMOCKIGBIRD

> JanE aUStEn - tO KILL a MOCKInGBIRD

{4,7} ⟹⟹ LOTOLSTOY - PRIDANDPRJUDIC

> LeO TOLSTOY - PRIDe AND PReJUDICe

{5,3} ⟹⟹ THUCODOYL - KI

> arTHUr COnan DOYLe (credit to @F1Krazy) - anna KarenIna (credit to @F1Krazy)

{1,9} ⟹⟹ M - THEHUFTHESEES

> vladiMir nabokov(?) - THE HoUnd oF THE baSkErvillES (credit to @F1Krazy)

{13,14} ⟹⟹ ERNES HEMNGWY - LOL

> ERNESt HEMiNGWaY - LOLita(?)

{4,12} ⟹⟹ XRU - THOTH

> aleXandRe dUmas (credit to @kayzeroshort) - THe Old man and THe sea

{4,7} ⟹⟹ AYLLY - TTUKT

> mArY sheLLeY - The Three mUsKeTeers (credit to @kayzeroshort)

Comment: {6,1} is Great Expectations; {8,2} part 2 is The Lord Of The Rings.

Comment: {4,7} is `m A r Y ` `s h e L L`  ___e___  `Y`

Comment: {5,3} is Arthur Conan Doyle - Anna Karenina (I think); {1,9} Pt.2 is The Hound of The Baskervilles

Comment: {9, 5} part 2 is The Catcher in the Rye

Comment: {9, 2} first part, J. D. Salinger

Comment: 24th Author, 25th book = Alexandre Dumas,The Three Musketeers

Comment: @Roger My guess for one of last one missing BMSTK - BraM SToKer, the blank one being Dracula then for him?

Comment: @n_palum I like it!

Comment: There's a guy named ted-lArrY PebWorth but he does not have any books that associated with the DNTOTHSOFT

Comment: The {8, 2} author is Anthony Powell, and the {17, 1} book is A Dance to the Music of Time.

Comment: I think someone wrote this as a comment and then deleted it, but the missing letters are any shared letters between the author and the book (not the author's true work, but the shifted one paired up with it.)