# The Shifted Music Library

Tags: knowledge, cipher, pattern, music

This is a spin-off and heavily inspired by [Levieux's puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49570/the-shifted-library) that I enjoyed helping answer/solve. And I've never used ciphers or things like this before so I wanted to learn some new puzzles :)

I have an alphabetically sorted collection of singles in my library. Unfortunately somebody shifted things around a bit and then deleted some stuff in all of the resulting pairs. Only the 26th pair is a correct match, although that's been scrambled even more and has become completely unrecognizable now. Can you figure out what it used to be? The numbers might help you.

Here are the 25 shifted pairs:

> **{2,N/A}** $\implies$ D - BBYERETIE 
> **{1,N/A}** $\implies$ RTYSPRS - LLJ 
> **{6,N/A}** $\implies$ IJCS - R 
> **{6,5}** $\implies$ CLTRCLB - HYJD 
> **{8,N/A}** $\implies$ HBS - IGOFING 
> **{5,N/A}** $\implies$ THBCKYSPS - OFM 
> **{5,N/A}** $\implies$ JL - CATTYUUTFMYA 
> **{10,7}** $\implies$ KYMNOGU - CARSSWHSPR 
> **{4,N/A}** $\implies$ GEORGEMCHEL - SUKYK 
> **{1,8}** $\implies$ KYK - JGIVEEREN 
> **{7,8}** $\implies$ PI&SS - -BMYH 
> **{4,10}** $\implies$ TNBRXTN - WILLLWYSLVEYU 
> **{11,N/A}** $\implies$ IUS - ,PRMA 
> **{10,N/A}** $\implies$ BS - U'ETHEETHATWAT
> **{7,N/A}** $\implies$ JHNV&IVINJHN -  
> **{3,7}** $\implies$ ABBA - HIPSDON'TLIE 
> **{1,N/A}** $\implies$ SHKIR - QUNDOQUNDOQUNDO 
> **{1,2}** $\implies$ ONYNIS - AHB 
> **{15,N/A}** $\implies$ CL - OHROSHUS 
> **{5,N/A}** $\implies$ QEE - RIGHTROD 
> **{8,1}** $\implies$ FLORID - MSSCHUSETTS 
> **{3,N/A}** $\implies$ BG - LOVTORY 
> **{9,N/A}** $\implies$ YOI - HEEE 
> **{3,2}** $\implies$ ROGRWHITTKR - SXYBCK 
> **{9,N/A}** $\implies$ JUSTNTMB - PY

And the 26th is: 
**{4,N/A}** $\implies$ BNL DIFF SOZ OPF - BZTWQ

*Apologies that some are really hard and some are obvious*

Comment: Is the missing letter scheme still those shared by the artist and song? If so, there seems to be an error in {9,N/A} ⟹⟹ YOWI - EWE, which clearly share a 'W'.

Comment: @kayzeroshort It does and you are totally right, whoops. Corrected and thank you

Comment: I think there is either an A missing or an A that shouldn't be there in {1,6} ⟹ KYK - JGIVEEREAN

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that...

> ...unlike the original puzzle, in which the titles were shifted one pair *down* from the correct author, here the songs have been shifted one pair *up* from the correct artist.

The full 25 pairs are:

{2,N/A} ⟹⟹ D - BBYERETIE

> Ma**d**onna (found by @kayzeroshort) - ...**B**a**by** On**e** Mo**re Ti**m**e** (found by @ClamSoapMan)

{1,N/A} ⟹⟹ RTYSPRS - LLJ

> B**r**i**t**ne**y Sp**ea**rs** (found by @ClamSoapMan) - Bi**ll**ie **J**ean (found by @LaniKate)

{6,N/A} ⟹⟹ IJCS - R

> M**i**chael **J**a**c**k**s**on - Ka**r**ma Chameleon (found by @LaniKate)

{6,5} ⟹⟹ CLTRCLB - HYJD

> **C**u**lt**u**r**e **Cl**u**b** - **H**e**y J**u**d**e

{8,N/A} ⟹⟹ HBS - IGOFING

> T**h**e **B**eatle**s** - **I Go**tta **F**eel**ing** (found by @LaniKate)

{5,N/A} ⟹⟹ THBCKYSPS - OFM

> **Th**e **B**la**ck** E**y**ed **P**ea**s** (found by @LaniKate) - All **Of M**e (found by @kayzeroshort)

{5,N/A} ⟹⟹ JL - CATTYUUTFMYA

> **J**ohn **L**egend (found by @kayzeroshort) - **Ca**n'**t** Ge**t Y**o**u** O**ut** O**f My** He**a**d

{10,7} ⟹⟹ KYMNOGU - CARSSWHSPR

> **Ky**lie **M**i**nogu**e - **Car**ele**ss Wh**i**sp**e**r**

{4,N/A} ⟹⟹ GEORGEMCHEL - SUKYK

> **George M**i**ch**a**el** - **Suk**i**y**a**k**i (found by @kayzeroshort)

{1,8} ⟹⟹ KYK - JGIVEEREN

> **Ky**u Sa**k**imoto - **J**ust **Give** M**e** A **Re**aso**n** (found by @LaniKate)

{7,8} ⟹⟹ PI&SS - -BMYH

> **Pi**nk **&** Nate Rue**ss** (found by @LaniKate) - Un-**B**reak **My H**eart

{4,4} ⟹⟹ TNBRXTN - WILLLWYSLVEYU

> **T**o**n**i **Br**a**xt**o**n** - I **Will** A**lw**a**ys L**o**ve Y**o**u**

{11,N/A} ⟹⟹ IUS - ,PRMA

> Wh**i**tney Ho**us**ton - Oh, **Pr**etty Wo**ma**n (found by @LaniKate)

{10,N/A} ⟹⟹ BS - U'ETHEETHATWAT

> Roy Or**b**i**s**on (found by @LaniKate) - Yo**u**'r**e** **The** On**e That** I **Wa**n**t** (found by @ClamSoapMan)

{7,N/A} ⟹⟹ JHNV&IVINJHN -

> **J**o**hn** Tra**v**olta **&** Ol**ivi**a **N**ewton-**J**o**hn** (found by @ClamSoapMan) - Waterloo

{3,2} ⟹⟹ ABBA - HIPSDON'TLIE

> **ABBA - Hips Don't Lie** (wow, that was hard)

{1,N/A} ⟹⟹ SHKIR - QUNDOQUNDOQUNDO

> **Sh**a**kir**a - **Qu**a**ndo Qu**a**ndo Qu**a**ndo** (found by @ClamSoapMan)

{1,7} ⟹⟹ ONYNIS - AHB

> T**ony** Re**nis** (found by @ClamSoapMan) - R**a**t**h**er **B**e (found by @LaniKate)

{15,N/A} ⟹⟹ CL - OHROSHUS

> **Cl**ean Bandit (found by @LaniKate) - An**o**t**h**e**r O**ne Bite**s** T**h**e D**us**t (@found by @ClamSoapMan)

{5,2} ⟹⟹ QEE - RIGHTROD

> **Q**u**ee**n - **Right Ro**un**d**

{8,7} ⟹⟹ FLORID - MSSCHUSETTS

> **Flo Rid**a - **M**a**ss**a**chusetts** (I see what you did there)

{3,N/A} ⟹⟹ BG - LOVTORY

> The **B**ee **G**ees (found by (@ClamSoapMan) - **Lov**e S**tory**

{9,N/A} ⟹⟹ YOI - HEEE

> Ta**y**l**o**r Sw**i**ft - T**he** Last Far**e**w**e**ll

{3,14} ⟹⟹ ROGRWHITKR - SXYBCK

> **Rog**e**r Whit**ta**k**e**r** - **S**e**xyB**a**ck**

{9,N/A} ⟹⟹ JUSTNTMB - PY

> **Just**i**n T**i**mb**erlake - Like a **P**ra**y**er (found by @kayzeroshort)

Big thanks to everyone who helped figure them out! As you can see:

> The missing letters in each of the mixed-up rows are the ones present in both the artist and the song name.

@kayzeroshort has noticed that

> The songs are listed alphabetically according to the nth letter in the song title, where n is the first number in the brackets. So, "B**a**by One More Time", "**B**illie Jean", "Karma **C**hameleon", and so on.

The next step is to

> take the nth letter of each song title, where n is the second number in the brackets. So, "Hey J**u**de", "Carele**s**s Whisper", and so on. These letters spell out "USE MY NAME".

So to decipher the 26th entry:

> You use a Vigenere cipher with "NPALUM" as the keyword. This nets you:
>  "OYL SOTS DOO UDS - MZICE". According to the OP, the songs are all from [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_best-selling_singles), and so I was able to identify the final answer as: "Royal Scots Dragoon Guard - Amazing Grace".

Comment: Lookin' good so far - I know the Abba one wasn't hard.. It just ended up that way and I didn't decide to change a whole bunch to fix it.. so it's a gimme.

Comment: Shakira is Quando Quando Quando
And the one below it is Tony Renis, but idk the song

Comment: 1st song is Baby One More Time. 2nd Artist Britney Spears. Queen song is Another One Bites the Dust

Comment: {11,N/A} ⟹⟹ IUS - ,PRMA 
Whitney Houston - song above it is I will always love you

Comment: John Travolta & Olivia Newton John, You're the one that I want

Comment: Also, Love Story is paired with The Bee Gees

Comment: Thanks @ClamSoapMan, I'll add those in (with credit) as soon as I can.

Comment: One thing I would recommend that helped with the last one was lower case for word and only upper case the ones that are given - helps you connect which letters are missing.. also connecting artist to song can help you figure some of them out... Wind beneath my wings is wrong I'll tell you that.

Comment: First artist is Madonna, last song is Like A Prayer.

Comment: I think Roger Whittaker's song might be The Last Farewell. However, the missing 'H' is problematic, as it is not shared by Taylor Swift.

Comment: @F1Krazy I apologize, I thought I double checked the letters... But as kayzero pointed out with the W that stayed in, that U should be missing, your initial thought is still correct.

Comment: Formatted the answer as you suggested, @n_palum. And thanks for clearling that up.

Comment: @kayzeroshort, I was ahead of you on the Roger Whittaker song but good call with "Madonna-Like a Prayer".

Comment: @n_palum If its supposed to be TAYLOR SWIFT - THE LAST FAREWELL, and we take out shared letters, then we should be left with YOI - HEEE. It looks like the 'THE' may have been left out (or The Last Farewell is not the right answer...)

Comment: @kayzeroshort I found where the mistake came from in my notes, I had part of my initial pairing scribbled out and forgot 'THE'.. thanks and sorry for the confusion.. it gets difficult staring at so many caps letters packed together sometimes

Comment: JL is wrong - rest look good so far

Comment: I'll have to look into who else sang "Hey Jude" then, because last time I checked, "The Beatles" doesn't have a "J" in it.

Comment: @F1Krazy Well JL wouldn't be the one lined up for that song in this list... so of course not.. You're looking at the list you have on your answer, which is not the full list. - You have 21 listed

Comment: PI&SS - -BMYH is Pink and Nate Russ for the artist and the song for KYK - JGIVEEREAN is Just give me a reason

Comment: sorry, make that Pink & Nate Ruess

Comment: {6,N/A} ⟹ IJCS - R  seems to be Michael Jackson - Karma Chameleon which would make {1,N/A} ⟹⟹ RTYSPRS - LLJ  Britney Spears - Billie Jean

Comment: 7th Artist, 6th song: John Legend - All of Me

Comment: working from @kayzeroshort 
{8,N/A} ⟹ HBS - IGOFING The Beatles - I gotta feeling
{5,N/A} ⟹ THBCKYSPS - OFM The Black Eyed Peas - All of Me

Comment: You can see that the list is alphabetized by the nth letter of the song, where n is the first number in brackets.

Comment: 10th artist, 9th song is Kyu Sakamoto, Sukiyaki

Comment: I believe that {11,N/A} ⟹ IUS - ,PRMA is Whitney Houston - Oh, Pretty Woman and 
{10,N/A} ⟹ BS - U'ETHEETHATWAT is Roy Orbison - You're The One That I Want

Comment: Sorry about the comment spam, {1,7} ⟹ ONYNIS - AHB is tony renis - Rather Be    and   
{15,N/A} ⟹ CL - OHROSHUS  is Clean Bandit - Another One Bites the Dust   and I think that's all of them done now.

Comment: Ah, you're probably right there, @n_palum, my mistake. I'll add those in (with credit) as soon as I can

Comment: @kayzeroshort That's a fantastic shout, well spotted

Comment: To each of you that's helped and done it so far, nice job, I'll confirm they are all correct, and your assumptions about the brackets so far are correct. Hint for the second number would be to think similarly to the puzzle this is based on -- ALSO I have to update the numbers, I just realized they got skewed slightly.... ugh

Comment: If the numbers were wrong, that might explain why I couldn't find what they were for. I was thinking like the original puzzle but kept coming out with gibberish. I'll try again, now they've been fixed.

Comment: @F1Krazy I think I messed it up in the cipher because the letters I left up are just the encryption letters from the letters that are not duplicates between author and song. Updating it.

Comment: I'm so close now, and yet still so far...

Comment: Almost there... If it helps these were all from the top selling singles of all time list XD

Comment: Try looking here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_best-selling_singles

Comment: Man, I never would have got that if I didn't know what I was looking for. Thanks for all the hints and corrections and stuff!